# Denied entry to the UK two years ago - will this affect my Student Visa application?

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa, students, denied-entry

My question has already probably been asked before, but I'm looking for some insight into my specific situation. Some basics on me - I'm a Canadian citizen, am not married and am 23 years old. Two years ago in April 2014 I was denied entry to the UK. I was travelling through Dublin to reach Belfast where I was to stay in a hostel for one month. In exchange for manning the front desk of the hostel for a couple of hours each day, I would be allowed to stay in one of their beds for free. The immigration officer saw this as work, and coupled with the fact that I did not have much money and no ticket to leave, I was denied entry. I was denied entry to the UK, but it all happened in Dublin. I totally understand the reasons for this, it was exceptionally stupid on my part. I have since been granted entry to Ireland twice, but I have not tried to go back to the UK.

Now, I've been accepted to study my Master's degree at King's College London. It would be a dream come true to study there. My plan is to defer for a year so that I can have as much time as possible to sort out my visa and to gather as much money as I can.

My question is: will my student visa be rejected because of this past incident?

Comment: Isn't the easiest way to find out to make the application as soon as permitted. I do think you should be especially careful to make the application accurate and well-supported to give yourself the best chance possible.

Comment: *The immigration  officer saw this as work* and rightfully so. If you are going to become an expat, it is worth looking into the immigration rules carefully. You do not want to violate the rules once inside the country.

Answer (score 5):

Since nobody with more knowledge has answered:

You were apparently honest about what you intended to do, but did not realize it was not permitted. That means you have not damaged your credibility. If you have the paperwork, there may be a reference number that will be useful on your future applications. In any case, be careful to fill in the application accurately.

King's College London admits a lot of international students. Not surprisingly, it has services to support them: [International Student Support](http://www.kcl.ac.uk/campuslife/services/student-advice-support/how/intlstudentsupport/index.aspx). They will know more about your specific situation, and how best to handle it, than anyone here. "Entry Clearance problems" is right at the top of the list of topics on which they advise. I strongly recommend asking them for help as soon as possible.